# roslaunch exit code 2 error

Tags: ros, computer-vision, errors

I am implementing a simple roslaunch file but I am getting an exit code 2 status I have pasted the exact log below any idea what would cause this and how I can rectify it.

```
kshitij@Kshitij:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch apriltag_ros apriltag.launch 
... logging to /home/kshitij/.ros/log/c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743/roslaunch-Kshitij-20782.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt 
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://Kshitij:38583/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: noetic
* /rosversion: 1.15.13

NODES
/
apriltag_ros (apriltag_ros/tagdetector.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [20790]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [20800]
started core service [/rosout] 
process[apriltag_ros-2]: started with pid [20803]
usage: tagdetector.py [-h] [-f FAMILIES] [-B N] [-t N] [-x SCALE] [-b SIGMA] [-0] [-1] [-2] [-c]
tagdetector.py: error: unrecognized arguments: __name:=apriltag_ros __log:=/home/kshitij/.ros/log/c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743/apriltag_ros-2.log
[apriltag_ros-2] process has died [pid 20803, exit code 2, cmd /home/kshitij/catkin_ws/src/apriltag_ros/scripts/tagdetector.py __name:=apriltag_ros __log:=/home/kshitij/.ros/log/c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743/apriltag_ros-2.log].
log file: /home/kshitij/.ros/log/c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743/apriltag_ros-2*.log
```

The launch file code is as below

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<launch>
    <node name = "apriltag_ros" pkg = "apriltag_ros" type = "tagdetector.py"  output="screen" />
</launch>
```

Edit 1: I have added the function that I am using to publish to ROS where the ROS node is initialised and used.

The function I am using to publish the data is as below

```
def location_publisher():
    """
    ROS Publisher: Publishes X, Y and Yaw values
    """
    pub = rospy.Publisher('apriltag_pose', tag, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('apriltag_ros', anonymous=False)
    msg = tag()
    msg.location.x = z # z in camera frame of reference is the distance from the tag i.e. x in general frame of reference
    msg.location.y = y
    msg.location.theta = yaw
    msg.status.data = status_tag
    msg.tagid.data = tag_id
    rospy.loginfo(msg)
    pub.publish(msg)

# Detect AprilTag
parser = ArgumentParser(description='Detect AprilTags from video stream.')
apriltagbase.add_arguments(parser)
options = parser.parse_args()

detector = apriltagbase.Detector(options, searchpath=apriltagbase._get_dll_path())

while(video.isOpened()):

    check,frame = video.read()
    
    if not check:
        break

    # overlay box on AprilTag format of detect_tags can be viewd in apriltag.py line 590.
    result,overlay = apriltagbase.detect_tags(frame, 
                                        detector,
                                        camera_params=(565.348501, 565.653872, 326.910261, 226.544390),
                                        tag_size=0.1688,
                                        vizualization=3,
                                        verbose=3,
                                        annotation=True
                                        )
    cv2.imshow('April Tag', overlay)
```

Link to the same question on the ROS Forum: https://answers.ros.org/question/391124/roslaunch-exit-code-2-error/

Comment: we will wait to see what answers you get on ros.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script I have added uses parses arguments defined in apriltagbase.

```
apriltagbase.add_arguments(parser)
options = parser.parse_args()
```

argparse fails for all arguments which are not added here. So need to replace it by

```
options, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

to prevent failing due to arguments added automatically by roslaunch.

Answer (score 1):

roslaunch expects you to be launching ROS nodes. And it's passing standard ROS nodes arguments such as the full name and log path. You're seeing the errors in it rejecting arguments `__name:` `__log:`

If you want to make this work you should use a script which is robust to receiving these extra arguments. Or wrap it in a script which will discard the extra arguments.

As a simple solution `rospy.init_node` will process those arguments. And you can access the stripped ones via `rospy.myargs` http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown

rosrun is a much lower level function that just executes the file from a different path

Comment: This is what I got on my post on answers.ros.org but this does not solve my problem as I am already using `rospy.init_node()`